# DNN CSM site azure DevOps release pipeline setup

Tags: azure-devops, content-management-system, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke

I am trying setup pipeline for DNN site CSM project . can you please suggest any articles to setup .

**i have below doubts**

1. As DNN is the CMS application development, whenever user modified from browser, data is updated in IIS, and in DB(if update the data from QA url, then QA DB will be updated, and files is updated in QA server only). Is there any procedure for auto check in (push the code) into Devops repository?
2. While import or export CMS data from QA to production, “Pageid” is creating automatically, and it is different in QA and production for the same page. Is there any chance to get the same page id for the same page in two environments using SQL script execution from Devops pielines?

Comment: This isn't really something DNN can do well. There are publishing options people have put together, but I've never come across one that works well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [blog](https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/vsts-dnn-dev-ops-continuous-integration-continuous-delivery-builds-azure) about DNN Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment with VSTS.

This tutorial will walk you through installing DNN Community Edition and set up VSTS builds that create versioned installer files and deploys the website to Azure.

Comment: But i need to publish in on-prem IIS server.